# Export data from Android to Excel file

Tags: android

I want to export data from Android to excel file

this is my button logic

```
public void exportProducts(View v) throws IOException {
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(" Product Data ");
        XSSFRow row;
        Map<String, Object[]> studentData = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
        int rowNumber = 1;
        studentData.put(
                "1",
                new Object[] { "ID", "NAME", "DESCRIPTION", "PRICE", "AMOUNT" });

        List<Product> updatedProductList = new ArrayList<>();
        float totalPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < productList.size(); j++) {
                if (productList.get(j).getName().equals(listView.getItemAtPosition(i))) {
                    rowNumber++;
                    studentData.put(
                            String.valueOf(rowNumber), new Object[] {
                                    String.valueOf(productList.get(j).getId()),
                                    productList.get(j).getName(),
                                    productList.get(j).getDescription(),
                                    (productList.get(j).getPrice()),
                                    String.valueOf(productList.get(j).getAmount())
                            }
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        Set<String> keyid = studentData.keySet();

        int rowid = 0;

        for (String key : keyid) {

            row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
            Object[] objectArr = studentData.get(key);
            int cellid = 0;

            for (Object obj : objectArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
                cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("D:\\WarehouseWithStocks\\savedexcelGFGsheet.xlsx")
        );
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
```

But when I try to press it show me this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:446)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\WarehouseWithStocks\savedexcelGFGsheet.xlsx: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.example.warehousewithstocks.ExportProductActivity.exportProducts(ExportProductActivity.java:160)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7255)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
        at com.example.warehousewithstocks.ExportProductActivity.exportProducts(ExportProductActivity.java:160) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I googled the error for read-only file system and found that I need to add in AndroidMaifest.xml these rows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But it didn't work again and gave me same error, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Mainfest add in aplication tag - android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

```
<manifest ... >
    <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android Q. -->
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
     ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: `new File("D:\\WarehouseWithStocks\\savedexcelGFGsheet.xlsx")` ???

Comment: change the file name with this -
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test.xlsx")